# Orientdb where clause not returning the record

Tags: sql, database, database-schema, orientdb, mbaas

I am trying to get a record using the id field from orientdb database, but it's not returning the record.

Here is the record (it works on a simple select):

```
orientdb {baasbox}> select from _bb_order             

----+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+---------+-----    ----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------
#   |@RID |price|_links|_allow|_audit|_author|verbatim|timestamp|audioLeng|orderURI |transcrip|_creation|id       |fileId   |feedbackI|status       

----+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------
0   |#22:1|0    |#11:9 |[1]   |#3:7  |k      |false   |false    |60       |TC0448...|         |2014-0...|249373...|8a9ca9...|0540df...|Order rece...

----+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------


1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.003 sec(s).
```

When I select the id from _bb_order schema, I can get the record.

```
orientdb {baasbox}> select id from _bb_order

----+-----+------------------------------------
#   |@RID |id                                  

----+-----+------------------------------------
0   |#-2:1|24937309-9189-484d-b406-6302b2ce9b6f

----+-----+------------------------------------


1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.003 sec(s).
```

BUT, I canNOT recover the record when I use a where clause on the 'id' attribute.

```
orientdb {baasbox}> select from _bb_order where id="24937309-9189-484d-b406-6302b2ce9b6f"    


0 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.001 sec(s).
```

I can get the record when I use some other attribute, like fileId.

```
orientdb {baasbox}> select from _bb_order where fileId="8a9ca9d2-bbe2-4326-aa2b-bad5f2032fbd"

----+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------
#   |@RID |price|_links|_allow|_audit|_author|verbatim|timestamp|audioLeng|orderURI |transcrip|_creation|fileId   |id       |feedbackI|status       

----+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------
0   |#22:1|0    |#11:9 |[1]   |#3:7  |k      |false   |false    |60       |TC0448...|         |2014-0...|8a9ca9...|249373...|0540df...|Order rece...

----+-----+-----+------+------+------+-------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------


1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.002 sec(s).
```

Confirmed that the Id field is stored as a String in the code.

Any thoughts on why this would be happening?

Comment: Do you have any index on _bb_order.id?
Try with: EXPLAIN select from _bb_order where id="24937309-9189-484d-b406-6302b2ce9b6f"

Comment: Can this database be corrupted? Like hardly shutdowned or something.

Comment: @enisher: I manually have to delete the entire database every time I need to drop the database. This is because when I use the drop database command and then create a new database, I get some error while logging in after creating a user. I realize this might be a bad thing to do, but it did solve the logging in problem.

Comment: @riccardo.tasso: I am not aware if there is any index on _bb_order.id or not. I tried 'rebuild index *' and it worked. I'll post here if the problem repeats and try the explain command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rebuild indexes with following command:

```
REBUILD INDEX *
```

If this is not helped, this might be a bug. In this case create an issue on github with description how to reproduce it.

Comment: Worked like magic! :) How often do I need to rebuild indexes? Do we manually have to build it every time or is there an automatic/ database command to do it?